# Limit the size of an Unordered list with jQuery for drop down menu

Tags: jquery, html

I'm having trouble using jQuery to limit the size of an UL list. I have a very large multi-tier list that is being used in a drop down menu. Some of the sub menu's have a ton of items in them and I'm trying to set a limit of 15-20 so the list doesn't span the entire page.

Here's basically what the list looks like:

```
<ul id="nav">
   <li><a href="#">Link 1</a>
       <ul class="subnav">
         <li><a href="#">Sub Link 1</a>
           <ul class="subnav">
              <li><a href="#"> Sub Link 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"> Sub Link 2</a></li> 
           </ul>
         </li>
         <li><a href="#">Sub Link 2</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Sub Link 3</a></li>
       </ul>
   </li>
```

And so on. For this I'm trying to limit the number of items in the subnav lists. In the second and third tiers of the list. I'm not very experienced with writing jQuery so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Where is the data that is creating this list coming from?

Answer (score 3):

Let's say your limit is 10 elements:

```
$('ul.subnav > li').slice(10).remove();
```

EDIT: See @linmic answer, you need to iterate each UL because slice() works on the whole matched subset of LIs (all of them, in my case).

Answer (score 1):

What I did when I had this was:
set subnav class Css to:

```
.subnav { height: 30px; overflow: auto; }
```

this will limit the showing range to 30 px, and add a scrollbar.

Aah ye, and if you really want to limit the amount of data it shows, you have to put a limit to where it gets the data from.

edit:

something like:

```
var amount = 0;
$('.subnav li').each(function() {
    amount++
    if (amount > 5) {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

but this will still display them in the code, only hide them, if you want them completely removed, use:

```
$(this).destroy();
```

still its faster for the page to do it earlier by code (fetch less data).

Comment: Yeah, that would work. But I'm trying to see if I can use jQuery to remove the additional items so they aren't still being displayed in the code. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Ah well first thing that pops to my mind is the .each() function, i'll edit my answer with a suggestion

Comment: destroy() doesn't exist but remove() does ;-)

Comment: Btw you're reinventing slice(), see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply do as following(say the limit is 4):

```
$('ul.subnav').each(function() { $(this).children('li').slice(4).hide(); });
```

And I've made a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/linmic/rB4aK/) for you, cheers.

NOTE: I would suggest you to use hide() instead of remove() for avoiding possible issues.

Comment: Nice correction if my answer which indeed fails even with the > selector. Of course jQuery applies the slice() on all matched LIs without resetting it between each UL, which you do here. I hoped there was an iteration-less solution ;-)

Comment: @Capsule According to current jQuery API, I don't see any solutions which can perfectly meet @Miles' requirement without iteration. If there's any, pls let me know. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
var leave = 3; // amount of items to be left in the menu
$('ul.subnav').each(function() {
    var $li = $(this).children().gt(leave - 1).hide();

    // optional - if you want to show them on user click
    $('<li><a href="#">...</a></li>')
        .appendTo(this)
        .find('a').click(function() {
            $(this).hide();
            $li.show();
        })
})
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Very creative emulation of `slice()` ;-)